# C# NET WinForms Alternative to DataGridView for displaying user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm writing a C# .NET WinForms app in which I have to create a new instance of a user control, which will contain several controls (TextBox, Button, CheckBox, etc.). The user controls must be created one at a time and stacked (arranged vertically).

Options I've tried:

**FlowLayoutPanel** doesn't have an index value that I can use to keep track of the many user controls that will be added when the user clicks the "Add New Item" button.

**DataGridView**  doesn't have a column type to accommodate a user control. While the DataGridView's functionality is much closer to what I need, I haven't found any code to add a column of type UserControl.

Any ideas?

Comment: _FlowLayoutPanel doesn't have an index value_ Well you add to the Controls collection and can use its index, as long as you don't remove as well.. It certainly is  the perfect control, made exactly for your situation. But you need to define more clearly just how you want to  access the UCs!

Comment: Emulating a DGV is never not a very drastic mistake, the painting expense will kill your program's perf dead.  Be sure to provide your own custom cell type, the tutorial [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need.

```
    protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e )
    {
        var tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            AutoScroll = true
        };

        Controls.Add( tableLayoutPanel );

        // To reset row and columns use this

        // Reset row count and styles
        tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 0;
        tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Clear();

        // Reset columns count and styles
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 0;
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();

        // For horizontal alignment we need add empty columns to fill space
        // |___emty fill___|Realcoulmn|___empty fill___|
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = 3;
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle( SizeType.Percent, 100 ) );  // Fill space
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle( SizeType.AutoSize ) );      // Real column with controls
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add( new ColumnStyle( SizeType.Percent, 100 ) );  // Fill space

        tableLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();

        for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            AddControl( tableLayoutPanel, 1 );
        }

        tableLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout( true );
    }

    public void IterateOverControls( TableLayoutPanel table )
    {
        // Iterate over all rows
        for ( var i = 0; i < table.RowCount; i++ )
        {
            var control = table.GetControlFromPosition( 1, i ); // Column 1
        }
    }

    public void AddControl( TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel, int column )
    {
        var btn = new Button { Text = "Hello vertical stack!" };
        btn.Click += button_Click;

        // Add row to tableLayoutPanel and set it style
        tableLayoutPanel.RowCount++;
        tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add( new RowStyle( SizeType.Absolute, btn.Height + 5 ) );

        // Add control to stack
        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add( btn, column, tableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 1 );
    }

    private void button_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        var btnControl = sender as Control;
        if ( btnControl == null )
            return;

        var tableLayoutPanel = btnControl.Parent as TableLayoutPanel;
        if ( tableLayoutPanel == null )
            return;

        AddControl( tableLayoutPanel, 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. I'll give the TableLayoutPanel a try.

Comment: OK, Dmitry, it works, but how will I add a new row to it with a button click from the button's Click() event handler? I tried to look for it with "foreach" but it isn't getting recognized.

Comment: @manicdrummer Look at example now, i added `IterateOverControls` method for iterate your controls in column. I also added an example of add controls from event handler and horizontal alignment of colums.

Comment: @manicdrummer if solution works, please mark this answer or describe the problem to solve it together.